# Phantom style in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document on which I run a macro to look for a style `Regular`.

My code is below:

```
If styleExisted = False Then
    For Each oRange1 In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        If oRange1.Characters.count > 0 And found = False Then
            oRange1.Select

            With Selection.Find
                .Style = "Regular"                  
            End With

            Selection.Find.Execute
            If Selection.Find.found = True Then
                test = Selection.range.Text

                found = True
                styleExisted = True
            End If
        End If
    Next oRange1
End If
```

However, the macro is giving me a false positive saying that content with the style is present in the document. I cannot find any content when I use the Find dialog with the style selected.

On debugging the code, `test` gets the first block of text in the document.
When I explicitly added some text with the style, the new text is being selected as expected.

On saving the file as `.docx` and checking the `document.xml` file, I find the below contents.

```xml
<w:tc>
    <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="1074" w:type="pct"/>
    </w:tcPr>
    <w:p w:rsidR="004B7F7E" w:rsidRPr="006E4FD7" w:rsidRDefault="004B7F7E" w:rsidP="006E4FD7">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="TableHead"/>
            <w:spacing w:after="0"/>
            <w:jc w:val="left"/>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rStyle w:val="Regular"/>
                <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
            </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="006E4FD7">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:bCs/>
                <w:sz w:val="24"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
            </w:rPr>
```

How can I get around this false positive?

This is happening only for some documents, which is really baffling.

EDIT: When I added some normal content from another document and put it at the beginning, the first block in the new content is being selected.

Also, there would have been some placeholder text(from a custom template) at the beginning in the `Regular` style; this would have been removed when the document was prepared.

Comment: So that paragraph is formatted as `TableHead`, but its [paragraph glyph](http://officeopenxml.com/WPparagraphProperties.php) is formatted as `Regular, 24 pt`.

Comment: Go to Add/Removes Programs, right click Office, and choose "Change" and then click `Repair`.  It's tends to fix little oddities like this. ([Alternate methods](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b))

Comment: `this would have been removed when the document was prepared` - and apparently its paragraph glyph remains. That is a common problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue with the below code:

```
'' remove empty paragraphs
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^13{2,}"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
'' remove empty paragraphs
```

Thanks @GSerg for your pointer regarding paragraph glyph.

EDIT:
I was still getting false positives, while using `.Style`; so I had to change my code as below, with the wildcard `<*>`:

```
With Selection.Find
    .Font.Italic = True
    .Font.Color = 32768
    .Text = "<*>"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
```